# I made an error answering a question in my ESTA application and as a result travel was denied. Is it possible to get a new passport and reapply?

Tags: esta

I made a clerical error, I answered yes to question 8: Have you stayed longer than 90 days in the US, without permission? I haven't.

Comment: What do you mean "travel was denied" ? Was the ESTA denied? Did you apply for a visa? In any event, whatever sanction or consequences flow from this apply to you _as a person_, and _not to your passport_. Getting a new passport is not a good tactic. If you're found out by the US authorities, you'll face much worse difficulties.

Comment: The ESTA application has enough information to find out you are the same person even if you change passport… including a question about other passports you have held.

Comment: What they wrote on the refusal email? If is is a clerical error, you should be able to reapply. Else, follow the procedure: you should apply for a visa: if it was just a clerical error, you should not have problem on getting it. But if the error was worse, just forget it for some time (a refusal of visa is stored in database, and often you must disclose it in other visa applications (to other countries).